# SQL statement not correct for creating a table with a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

I'm not sure why the SQL isn't working for the Class table. I know the problem has to do with the foreign key line, if I remove that the table will be created. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

The error I receive is: Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'university.class' (errno: 150)

```
CREATE TABLE Faculty (
    facId VARCHAR(6),
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    department VARCHAR(20),
    rank VARCHAR(10),
    CONSTRAINT Faculty_facId_pk PRIMARY KEY (facId));

DROP TABLE Class;

CREATE TABLE Class (
    classNumber VARCHAR(8),
    facId VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    schedule VARCHAR(8),
    room VARCHAR(6),
    CONSTRAINT Class_classNumber_pk PRIMARY KEY (classNumber),
    CONSTRAINT Class_facId_fk FOREIGN KEY (facId) REFERENCES Faculty (facId) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Class_schedule_room_uk UNIQUE (schedule, room));
```

Comment: Did the table Faculty actually get created?  I don't work with mySql but having a nullable primary key column is not permitted with other database engines.  Even if mySql allows it, it seems to be a very bad idea.

Comment: @DanBracuk - The primary key is not nullable.

Comment: Yeah the faculty table was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `ON DELETE SET NULL` but `Class.facID` does not allow nulls so it would not be possible.

[This works](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f1769/1) and deletes the parent record leaving the column `NULL` in the orphan.

```
CREATE TABLE Faculty (
    facId VARCHAR(6),
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    department VARCHAR(20),
    rank VARCHAR(10),
    CONSTRAINT Faculty_facId_pk PRIMARY KEY (facId));



CREATE TABLE Class (
    classNumber VARCHAR(8),
    facId VARCHAR(6) NULL,
    schedule VARCHAR(8),
    room VARCHAR(6),
    CONSTRAINT Class_classNumber_pk PRIMARY KEY (classNumber),
    CONSTRAINT Class_facId_fk FOREIGN KEY (facId) REFERENCES Faculty (facId) ON DELETE set null,
    CONSTRAINT Class_schedule_room_uk UNIQUE (schedule, room));


INSERT INTO Faculty 
VALUES('1','Foo','foo','foo');


INSERT INTO Class 
VALUES('1','1','foo','foo');

DELETE FROM Faculty;
```

Comment: That makes sense I was thinking it set NULL for the parent. Thanks for explaining that.

Answer (score 1):

Foreign key should not be NULL

CREATE TABLE Class (

```
classNumber VARCHAR(8),

facId VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,

schedule VARCHAR(8),

room VARCHAR(6),

CONSTRAINT Class_classNumber_pk PRIMARY KEY (classNumber),

CONSTRAINT Class_facId_fk FOREIGN KEY (facId) REFERENCES Faculty (facId)  ,

CONSTRAINT Class_schedule_room_uk UNIQUE (schedule, room))
```